# Losing screen object auto-focus

Tags: android, gridview, focus, autofocus

I have a GridView displaying buttons to different screens of my app.  When this grid screen, the first cell is selected.  Is there a way to programmatically have no cells selected when the screen launches?  Or do I have to hide the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When this grid screen, the first cell is selected.

That should only be true if the user was using the navigator (D-pad, trackball, etc.) in the previous activity.

> Is there a way to programmatically have no cells selected when the screen launches?

Generally, the user determines this based on [whether they are in touch mode or not](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html). You could try `setSelection(-1)` or something, but I would not be surprised if this fails to work.

> Or do I have to hide the selector?

I would recommend just following the platform conventions. If the user is using the D-pad or trackball, they probably **want** to use the D-pad or trackball, and disabling the selector will simply make them frustrated with you and your app. Please see the article I linked to above for more details on touch mode and why it works the way it does.

Comment: Ah, I see why this is happening.  When I launch the app, the user is taken to a login screen.  One of the EditTexts for username/pw will have focus.  I type and then hit the enter button, which moves focus to the login button, but this is apparently also like using the trackpad to scroll to the next object.